# Typescript compiler API set up error: No gulpfile found

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to follow the **Getting set up** section [here (Using the Compiler API)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

This results in the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Volker\Desktop\ts-projects\using-the-compiler> npm install -g typescript

changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\Volker\Desktop\ts-projects\using-the-compiler> npm link typescript
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Volker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gulp build-eslint-rules
npm ERR! [13:58:28] No gulpfile found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Volker\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-15T12_58_28_853Z-debug.log
```

My node version is `v16.13.1`.

What did I do wrong? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's up with those instructions (probably out of date). Just do `npm install --save typescript` then import it as usual:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
```

Comment: Yeah, i just installed locally. Didn't link anything and it's working.